# Regex (ruby) to remove all instances of a set of characters EXCEPT when they are at the start of a string

Tags: regex, ruby

I want to remove all instances of these characters `["+", "-", "~"]` from a string, except when they occur at the start of the string.

For example:

```
"abc"   => "abc"
"ab+c"  => "abc"
"+abc"  => "+abc"
"-+abc" => "-abc"
"ab+-c" => "abc"
```

Note with the fourth one that the `+` is removed, because it wasn't the first character.  So, if there are multiple "unwanted" characters at the start of a string, we only keep the first one.

I can't quite figure out the regex syntax for this.  Can anyone help?  I'm using Ruby but regex syntax **tends** to be the same across languages.

Comment: The language makes a difference since Ruby regex is somewhat specific (especially when it comes to start of *string* matching). Is there any pattern you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't change the string: `"+ab-c"..gsub(/^(![\+\-\~])/,"")`

Comment: Please add that to the question.

Comment: Non-regex solution: `str[1..-1] = str[1..-1].delete('+~-')`

Comment: @Stefan in ruby 2.6+ we can now use `str[1..]` in place of `str[1..-1]`. Also OP be careful to use `'+~-'` and not `'+-~'` because the first will remove those 3 characters and the second will remove all characters between `+` (43) and `~` (126) because the `-` is viewed as referencing a range of characters in this case

Comment: Further to @engineersmnky's point, `'-+~'` and `'+\-~'` (or `"+\\-~"`) are also OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^(![\+\-\~]` pattern matches the start of a *line* and then captures into Group 1 a `!` char followed with `+`, `-` or `~` char, so you remove only `!+`, `!~` or `!-` at the start of a line.

You may use

```
/(?!\A)[+~-]/
```

It matches any `+`, `~` or `-` char (`[+~-]`) that are not at the start of the string (`(?!\A)`). The `(?!\A)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if its pattern is not matched immediately to the right of the current location. If the location is at the start of the string (`\A` assets this very position), the match is failed. Since `\A` is an anchor that does not consume any text, a so-called zero-length pattern, there is no difference if you use a lookahead or lookbehind, `(?<!\A)`.

Make sure `-` is either at the start or end of the character class, and you won't have to escape it.

[Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/lf8z8F):

```
strs = ["abc", "ab+c", "+abc", "-+abc", "ab+-c"]
strs.each { |x| p x.gsub(/(?!\A)[-+~]/, "") }
```

Output:

```
"abc"
"abc"
"+abc"
"-abc"
"abc"
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks!  `"-+ab-c+d".gsub(/(?!\A)[+~-]/,"") => "-abcd"`.  So, `(?!\A)` means "not the start"?  What is the `\A` doing?

Comment: ``\A`` is the *start of the string*.

Comment: Ah, i thought that's what `^` was.

Comment: @MaxWilliams In Ruby regex, `^` matches the *line* start.

Comment: oh yes, for multiline strings.  I see.  thanks a lot.

Comment: Another (less desirable) way: `"-cats+dogs".gsub(/(.)[+~-]/, '\1')
 => "-catsdogs"`.

Comment: I thought of this approach, too, but deliberately did not add to the answer.

Comment: I would not have added it either, in our shared belief that including less-desirable solutions only waters-down answers, but at the same time I think it's worth mentioning in a comment. One never knows when an inferior approach to one problem may lead to a good solution to another (though I guess any answer could be justified on that basis).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think it's worth mentioning, as a side point, thanks.  I agree that it's not as clean as the accepted answer but it's always good to learn more about the arcane subject of regexes :)

Comment: @MaxWilliams Then to complete this conversation, you actually would use `.gsub(/(.)[+~-]/m, '\1')` since `.` by default does not match line break chars and `m` flag is required for that.